# How to proccess DELETE, PUT methods using query in django rest frameworks viewsets?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-views

Im a newbie in Django and now im writing rest api for my web-application.
Im using token authentication and it works fairly well.
I already have the following models, views, serializers and router in my app (hotels_app):

**models.py**

```
class Hotel(UUIDMixin):
    company = models.CharField(_('company'), max_length=config.CHARS_DEFAULT, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=config.CHARS_DEFAULT)
    star_rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        verbose_name=_('star rating'),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(5)],
    )
    rooms_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('rooms quantity'))
    phone = PhoneNumberField(
        verbose_name=_('phone'),
        max_length=config.PHONE_LENGTH,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    check_in = models.CharField(_('check in'), max_length=config.CHECK_IN_OUT_LEN)
    check_out = models.CharField(_('check out'), max_length=config.CHECK_IN_OUT_LEN)
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(_('country'), max_length=config.CHARS_DEFAULT)
    state = models.CharField(_('state'), max_length=config.CHARS_DEFAULT, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(_('city'), max_length=config.CHARS_DEFAULT)
    street = models.CharField(_('street'), max_length=config.CHARS_DEFAULT)
    building = models.CharField(_('building'), max_length=config.CHAR_BUILD_LENGTH)
    latitude = models.FloatField(
        verbose_name=_('latitude'),
        validators=[MinValueValidator(-config.LATITUDE), MaxValueValidator(config.LATITUDE)],
    )
    longitude = models.FloatField(
        verbose_name=_('longitude'),
        validators=[MinValueValidator(-config.LONGITUDE), MaxValueValidator(config.LONGITUDE)],
    )
    amenities = models.ManyToManyField(Amenity, verbose_name=_('amenities'), through='HotelAmenity')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}, {self.country}'

    class Meta:
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=['name'], name='hotel_name_idx')]
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=models.Q(star_rating__gte=0) & models.Q(star_rating__lte=5),
                name='star_rate_check',
            ),
            models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(rooms_quantity__gt=0), name='rooms_quan_check'),
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=models.Q(latitude__gte=-config.LATITUDE) & models.Q(latitude__lte=config.LATITUDE),
                name='latitude_check',
            ),
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=models.Q(longitude__gte=-config.LONGITUDE) & models.Q(longitude__lte=config.LONGITUDE),
                name='longitude_check',
            ),
        ]
        ordering = ['name']
        db_table = 'hotel'
        verbose_name = _('hotel')
        verbose_name_plural = _('hotels')
```

**serializers.py**

```
class HotelSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Hotel
        fields = (
            'id', 'company', 'name',
            'star_rating', 'rooms_quantity', 'phone',
            'check_in', 'check_out', 'description',
            'country', 'state', 'city', 'street',
            'building', 'latitude', 'longitude',
        )
```

**views.py**

```
class Permission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, _):
        if request.method in config.SAFE_METHODS:
            return bool(request.user and request.user.is_authenticated)
        elif request.method in config.UNSAFE_METHODS:
            return bool(request.user and request.user.is_superuser)
        return False


def query_from_request(request, serializer=None) -> dict:
    if serializer:
        query = {}
        for attr in serializer.Meta.fields:
            attr_value = request.GET.get(attr, '')
            if attr_value:
                query[attr] = attr_value
        return query
    return request.GET

def create_viewset(model, serializer):
    class CustomViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        serializer_class = serializer
        permission_classes = [Permission]

        def get_queryset(self):
            instances = model.objects.all()
            query = query_from_request(self.request, serializer)
            if query:
                instances = instances.filter(**query)
            return instances

    return CustomViewSet

HotelViewSet = create_viewset(Hotel, serializers.HotelSerializer)
```

**urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'amenity', views.AmenityViewSet, basename='amenity')
router.register(r'hotel', views.HotelViewSet, basename='hotel')
router.register(r'room', views.RoomViewSet, basename='room')

urlpatterns = [
    # REST
    path('rest/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

GET requests are working pretty fine with queries:
ex. Im going to url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest/hotel/?company=some_company/`
And it gives me all the instances that include that company

What im trying to reach is to use the same queries to DELETE, PUT methods.
I use Postman and go to url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest/hotel/?company=some_company/` and try to delete these instances but I get this response from server:

```
{
    "detail": "Method \"DELETE\" not allowed."
}
```

I also send Authorization header: `Authorization: Token <user_token>`

I made some research in docs, internet and stack overflow as well but this didnt help much

I know that DefaultRouter uses this url style for DELETE: `{prefix}/{lookup}/[.format]`

1. I have tried adding MultipleFieldLookupMixin class in viewset:

```
class MultipleFieldLookupMixin:
    """
    Apply this mixin to any view or viewset to get multiple field filtering
    based on a `lookup_fields` attribute, instead of the default single field filtering.
    """
    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()             # Get the base queryset
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)  # Apply any filter backends
        filter = {}
        for field in self.lookup_fields:
            if self.kwargs.get(field): # Ignore empty fields.
                filter[field] = self.kwargs[field]
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter)  # Lookup the object
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        return obj
```

And i have changed my **views.py** a little bit:

```
def create_viewset(model, serializer, lookups):
    class CustomViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, MultipleFieldLookupMixin):
        serializer_class = serializer
        permission_classes = [Permission]
        lookup_fields = lookups

        def get_queryset(self):
            instances = model.objects.all()
            query = query_from_request(self.request, serializer)
            if query:
                instances = instances.filter(**query)
            return instances

    return CustomViewSet


hotel_lookup = [
    'pk', 'company', 'name',
    'star_rating', 'rooms_quantity',
    'country', 'state', 'city', 'street',
    'building',
]

HotelViewSet = create_viewset(Hotel, serializers.HotelSerializer, hotel_lookup)
```

But using the same url with DELETE method: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest/hotel/?company=some_company/`
I get 'method not allowed', i even tried: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest/hotel/company=some_company/`, it returns the same thing

2. Another thing that i have tried is overriding destroy and update methods of viewset:

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            query = query_from_request(request, serializer)
            if query:
                instances = cls_model.objects.filter(**query)
                objects_num = len(instances)
                if not objects_num:
                    msg = f'DELETE query {query} did not match any instances of {cls_model.__name__}'
                    return Response(msg, status=status_codes.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
                try:
                    instances.delete()
                except Exception as error:
                    return Response(error, status=status_codes.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                msg = f'DELETED {objects_num} instances of {cls_model.__name__}'
                status = status_codes.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT if objects_num == 1 else status_codes.HTTP_200_OK
                return Response(msg, status=status)
            return Response('DELETE has got no query', status=status_codes.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            def serialize(target):
                payload = parsers.JSONParser().parse(request)
                if target:
                    serialized = serializer(target, data=payload, partial=True)
                    status = status_codes.HTTP_200_OK
                    body = f'PUT has updated instance of {cls_model.__name__} id={target.id}'
                else:
                    serialized = serializer(data=payload, partial=True)
                    status = status_codes.HTTP_201_CREATED
                    body = f'PUT has created a new instance of {cls_model.__name__}'

                if not serialized.is_valid():
                    return status_codes.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, f'PUT could not process content: {payload}'

                try:
                    serialized.save()
                except Exception as error:
                    return status_codes.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, error
                return status, body

            query = query_from_request(request, serializer)
            target_id = query.get('id', '')
            if target_id:
                target_object = cls_model.objects.get(id=target_id)
                status, body = serialize(target_object)
                return Response(body, status=status)
            return Response('PUT has got no id primary key', status=status_codes.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Postman returns the same: 'method not allowed' for both DELETE and PUT methods.

Maybe someone came across such thing and knows how to proccess requests with queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is to route the `DELETE` method for the "list" view of a `ModelViewSet`, which is not supported by default in Django rest framework.

What you need to do is use [the `@action(...)` decorator](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) to add the functionnality to your `ModelViewSet`. I made a minimal example that achieves what you are trying to do with the `DELETE` method :

```py
from django.db import models

class Hotel(models.Model):
    textval = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    intval = models.IntegerField()

from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

class HotelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Hotel
        fields = ["id", "textval", "intval"]

from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

class Permission(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, _):
        print(f"Hello from permission {request}")
        return True  # Put your actual permission checks here

from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response

def query_from_request(request, serializer=None):
    if serializer:
        query = {}
        for attr in serializer.Meta.fields:
            attr_value = request.GET.get(attr, '')
            if attr_value:
                query[attr] = attr_value
        return query
    return request.GET

class HotelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = HotelSerializer
    permission_classes = [Permission]

    def get_queryset(self):
        instances = Hotel.objects.all()
        query = query_from_request(self.request, HotelSerializer)
        if query:
            instances = instances.filter(**query)
        return instances

    @action(detail=False, methods=['delete'])
    def delete(self, request):
        delete_query = self.get_queryset()
        delete_instances = list(delete_query)
        delete_query.delete()
        return Response(self.serializer_class(delete_instances, many=True).data)
```

The important part is at the end of this code snippet :

- The `@action(...)` decorator allows you to add new actions to your viewsets. Its parameters tell how this action should be routed  :

  - `detail=False` tells that you do not expect a `{lookup}` part in your URL. You usually use this when you don't want to access a specific instance.
  - `methods=['delete']` has a clear meaning.
- The short implementation for `delete(...)` in this example seems to work just right. It gets the instances it needs to delete from the `get_queryset()` method, just like default actions, deletes it, and responds with what it just deleted.

As an additional perk, this also works with the Browsable API (which is a nice feature from DRF if you don't know about it).

I'll leave it to you to implement the `PUT` equivalent using this, but feel free to ask for help if you need it.